# How to pass values from javascript file to file where node js stuff is done and the return certain data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

This is my form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <div class="alert alert-error" id="reg-error"></div>
  <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="reg=name">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="reg-name" id="reg-name" class="form-control" required placeholder="namerinho">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="reg-email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" name="reg-email" id="reg-email" class="form-control" required placeholder="surnaminho">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="reg-pass">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="reg-pass" class="form-control" required placeholder="******">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" >
    <label for="reg-pass2">Confirm Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="reg-pass2" class="form-control" required placeholder="******">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-default" name="Register-btn" id="Register-btn" type="button">Register</button> 
</form>
```

html file has link to script.js
This is my script.js (so far):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#abv" ).click(function() {
    $.post('script/register'); // here I expect to get return true or false
  });
});
```

and this is register code to which i make http request:

```
var userOrEmailExists = false;
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  port     : 3307,
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'database'
});

connection.query('select email, username from users',function(err, rows) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  var users;
  users = rows;
  var c = 0;
  var x = 'asd';
  for (var i = users.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (user === users[i].username || email ===users[i].email){
        userOrEmailExists = true;
    }
  }
});
// if(userOrEmailExists === true){// I will insert data here}

connection.end();

return userOrEmailExists;
```

And as I planned on Post I will pass input values to `register.js` and there I will check if that kind of user exists or not and then either insert or not. I am not sure if this is a good idea to do that, but as I planned everything will done on button click(and `register.js` will return true or false) So again, just to be clear, My question is how to pass variables from `script.js` to `register.js` and then return a boolean value and do something with it in script js. Thank you!!

Comment: I guess its something with module.exports, but still can't figure it out.

Comment: But still cant figure it out how to do that without using me using terminal and calling that file by myself...

Comment: Probably a dup of [How do I return a value from an asynchronous function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).  `connection.query()` is async and finishes long after your function has already returned.  So, you can't do `return userOrEmailExists;` because `userOrEmailExists` has not yet been set when your function returns.

Comment: Thanks you very much. Link you gave me is very useful :)